# CSS Adaptive height issue

Tags: css

I am having some issues while building a adaptive website. See how it should be:

http://tweakers.net/ext/f/O1sEWJd53lwKA3Gv3W0CJDgW/full.png

I have this code in my css:

```
.HTML { 
    min-width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
} 

.page { 
    margin-top: 4.3%; /* 215px : 4960px */ 
    margin-left: 4.76%; /* 172px : 3615px */ 
    margin-right: 4.6%; /* 168px : 3615px */ 
    height: 100%; 
} 

.header { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 13.95%; /* 661px : 4737px */ 
} 

.logo { 
    margin-left: 7.51%; /* 246px : pagewidth */ 
    width: 28%; /* 918px : pagewdith */ 
    height: auto; 
    float: left; 
} 

.searchbox { 
    margin-top: 24.4%; /* 161px : 661px */ 
    float:right; 
    width: 22.4%; /* 737px : pagewidth */ 
}
```

The logo shows as it should, but the margin-top of the searchbox seems to be the margin from the top of the HTML, not from the top of the header class. It get ways too low. I need it to be responsive because the height of the image is responsive, too, so the searchbox should adapt to the height of the logo because their bottoms are aligned.

Furthermore, I have another class which should have a height of 5% of the header height, but when I give it height: 5%; it gets a height of 0px in Chrome 23... How does this come?

My HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <img />
            </div>
            <div class="searchbox"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you post some of your HTML, too?

Comment: have a little bit problems with formatting it right for this site, but here is my HTML:
`<body>
    <div class="page">
     <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
       <img />
      </div>
      <div class="searchbox">
   
      </div>
        </div>
   </div>`

Answer (score 0):

"try putting a position: relative to the parent and position: absolute to the child."
-cybershot

Source: http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/9608/solved-margin-extends-beyond-parent/p1

This workaround is the closest I've got to in solving this.